Clean up of Jenkins all stages workspace before starting of a new build
I have a Jenkins pipeline with parallel stages, which looks something like this:
               / -- build -- test-xyz -- test-123--\
-- workspace--/                                     |--- Analyse -- upload results 
               \-- build -- test-abc -- test-456 --/

Parallel stages run on separate node and will consume workspace like w1,w1@1,w1@2,w1@3. I want to delete all of these before starting a new build. I have tried the usage of cleanWs() but we need those workspace till next build. That's why i am looking for some option to clean workspaces just before the new build.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated?
Expecting a solution to clean all workspaces like w1, w1@1,w1@2 etc., before starting a new build.

You can use cleanWs() before the build, plugin documentation has an example:
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        // This is required if you want to clean before build
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Clean before build
                cleanWs()
                // We need to explicitly checkout from SCM here
                checkout scm
                echo "Building ${env.JOB_NAME}..."
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you for the answer!! I did try that, but i could still see other stages workspace like w1@1, w1@2 etc. I am looking for something which can clean complete workspace for w1*
